# Javascript array.some: pass params to callback

Tags: javascript

I learned about array.some() and want to use it for a check if an object property is already set for any object in an array.

But I cannot get it working. I dont know how to pass the params to the callback function.

```
function hasPropertyValue(obj, property, value){
    return (obj[property] === value);
}

let arr = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Name1'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Name2'}
];

console.log(arr.some(hasPropertyValue(element, 'id', 1)));   //Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

By doing `arr.some(hasPropertyValue(element, 'id', 1))` you pass the *result* of calling `hasPropertyValue` to `.some`, instead you want to pass *the function itself* to it. That could be done with `arr.some(hasPropertyValue)`, but the arguments of `.some` do not match the parameters of `hasPropertyValue`. So you need to pass a function, that then calls your function:

```
function hasPropertyValue(obj, property, value){
    return (obj[property] === value);
}

let arr = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Name1'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Name2'}
];

console.log(arr.some(element => hasPropertyValue(element, 'id', 1)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a closure over the wanted key and value and return a function which gets the object from the calling method.

```js
function hasPropertyValue(property, value) {
    return function(object) {
        return (object[property] === value);
    };
}

let arr = [{ id: 1, name: 'Name1' }, { id: 2, name: 'Name2' }];

console.log(arr.some(hasPropertyValue('id', 1)));
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing inside array.some needs to be a function, not the result of a function call. ie

`arr.some(element => hasPropertyValue(element, 'id', 1));`

Answer (score 0):

***array.some()*** method checks if at least one element in the array matches a condition defined in a ***'validator function'***.

It requires only the name of the ***validator function*** as the parameter. 
Best practice is to use the ***validator function*** without arguments.

**Here is a fix for the above mentioned problem:**

```
// File name: array_some_demo.js

function hasPropertyValue(array_element) {
    // Verify if the 'id' attribute of the element is 1
    return (array_element.id === 1)
}

let arr = [
    { id: 100, name: 'Name100'},
    { id: 1, name: 'Name1'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Name2'}
]


//  Call the .some method with 'hasPropertyValue' as the parameter.
//  This will initiate a loop of hasPropertyValue on all elements.
// 
//  Execution breaks out of the loop 
//  when an element with 'id' value of 1 is found.

console.log(arr.some(hasPropertyValue))
```

**Output:**

$ node array_some_demo.js

> true